# Bash script not working properly when run automatically

Tags: bash, networking, ubuntu, notifications, system

I have a bash script that prints a notification using the notify-OSD only when my laptop is connected to a network. So I have placed the bash script in /etc/network/if-up.d

I printed some log messages into a file to confirm that the script is indeed running. However the notification thing does not seem to work. I just added this line to the file

```
 notify-send -u 'critical' -i /home/vivek/Downloads/proxy.ico 'SetProxy Status' 'proxy set to auto'
```

However when i run that script explicitly (by double clicking on it or) from the terminal like this:

```
cd /etc/network/if-up.d
./setproxy
```

setproxy is the name of the bash file, then i see the notification working perfectly. Why this behaviour? How can i fix this? I am using ubuntu 12.04

Output in /tmp/trace :

```
+ nmcli con status
+ grep -q 'Hostel\|IITD'
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode none

** (process:12320): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch     --autolaunch=673e71ca3fc5f402403d22380000000a --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n

** (process:12320): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=673e71ca3fc5f402403d22380000000a --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with   non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
+ echo 'You are outside college! No Proxy'
+ notify-send -u critical -i /home/vivek/Downloads/proxy.ico 'SetProxy Status' 'You are outside college, proxy set to none'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `DISPLAY`, you have to set `XAUTHORITY` too, but that's a little more complicated (depending on username and a random string) try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export displayOwner=vivek     # enter your usename here
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=$(echo /var/run/gdm3/auth-for-${displayOwner}-*/database)

notify-send -u 'critical' -i /home/vivek/Downloads/proxy.ico 'SetProxy Status' 'proxy set to auto'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect an environment problem.

So in your script, put :

```
#!/bin/bash -x

source ~/.bashrc || source /etc/profile
exec &>/tmp/trace
# rest of the script there
```

and tell us what's going on.

**Edit** : Your script should start with :

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/.bashrc || source /etc/profile
export DISPLAY=:0
# rest of the script there
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Just to be clear, Do you mean i need to add something like this: #! source ~/.bashrc || /etc/profile instead of the usual #!/bin/bash ?

Comment: @VivekPradhan, no, `source` should be on the *next* line after the `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Ok @sputnick i tried this :
#!bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc || source /etc/profile , but i still do not see the notification. You can try and put a trivial bash script that just shows a notification and put it in /etc/network/if-up.d and let me know how you got it working.

Comment: See my edited post for debug mode. Then edit your original post with the output from /tmp/trace file

Comment: Thanks a lot @sputnick! I have updated my question with the output from /tmp/trace

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @sputnick , adding "export DISPLAY=:0 && export XAUTHORITY=/home/vivek/.Xauthority " to my script fixed the error with notifications. I just exported Display without exporting Xauthority and i was still getting some Xauthorisation error, http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/DBus%20notify-send%20over%20network.htm really explains this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the program you are running requires X, it cannot run without X. Either somehow authorize it to connect to your X session, or run it from within your X session.

Comment: Thanks a lot @triplee for your reply. I guess you are right, but i don't understand why would it need Xauthorisation? I will try and found out how can i export Xsession variables for authorization.