# when linux system calls scripts some commands don't work ( cron / if-up.d )

Tags: linux, cron, zenity, xclip

Hi I'm trying to run a script that calls **xclip** in order to have a string ready to paste when i connect to the internet.

I have a script **/etc/network/if-up.d/script** that does execute when connecting (i make him post a date in a file succesfuly ) but the **xclip** instruction seems not to work, there's nothing to paste. If i call this script manually by typing /etc/network/if-up.d/script in a console it works perfectly.

If i try to launch a **zenity** message it also don't appeare when connecting. Again if i do it by hand it appeares.

Then I have a expect script that calls matlab (console mode), if I execute it manually it works but if i call it from **cron** it freezees when calling the script.

It's driving me crasy since it seems that only certain commands in a script can be executed when the system calls them automaticaly.

I'v tryed to call the instructions with **nohup instruction &** but still misses

Comment: Your cron script is not running in the context of your logged-in user; your cron script (when executed by cron) has no visibility into your desktop session, etc.  I don't think you can launch X apps into your desktop from cron since it's unaware of your environment.

Answer (score 1):

This is working as designed, you search around and will see compliated ways to resolve this issue, or you can use xmessage as I describe here:  [Using Zenity in a root incron job to display message to currently logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706194/using-zenity-in-a-root-incron-job-to-display-message-to-currently-logged-in-user/24070682#24070682)

**Easy option 1:  xmessage (in the script)**

```
MSSG="/tmp/mssg-file-${RANDOM}" 
echo -e " MESSAGE \n ==========\n Done with task, YEY. " > ${MSSG}
xmessage -center -file ${MSSG} -display :0.0 
[[ -s ${MSSG} ]] && rm -f ${MSSG}
```

**Easy option 2:  set the DISPLAY (then should work)**

```
    export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/somedirectory/somecommand
```

Answer (score 0):

question is answered here for cron :

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-105250.html

and here for if-up network :

[Bash script not working properly when run automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092475/bash-script-not-working-properly-when-run-automatically)